# Why isn't longest common substring solution to stemming algorithm?

Tags: string, algorithm, search, language-agnostic, search-engine

I was reading about a stemming which is the problem of matching words to a common root and seems to be a standard problem in search engines.
When I first thought about this problem, I thought that this is a classic application of the longest common substring problem applied to `N` words.
E.g. for the words `{computation, compute, computers}` the longest common substring is `compute` and this is the stem/root.
But I read that this is not the solution to the problem. Actually it [seems](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stemming) that this is not even a consideration and other approaches (suffix removal, stochastic etc) are the standard solutions.

My question is: why isn't the longest common substring of `N` words a solution to this problem?

Comment: One thing that springs to mind is that the LCS may not be a prefix...

Comment: @OliCharlesworth:Hm.Then Longest Common Prefix using prefix tries?

Comment: So you have an English word and you want to reduce it to its stem. What exactly do you apply LCS to?

Comment: Yes, that would work in your example.  But it wouldn't work for applications where you're interested in non-trivial morphology (e.g. "dries" --> "dry").

Comment: @NPE:This would apply to a series of words

Comment: @OliCharlesworth:But I would not lose their connection.`dr` is their common stem.As long as they have a common prefix they are connected

Comment: @Cratylus: But obtaining "dr" isn't very useful, in general.

Comment: @Olicharlesworth:But the actual problem is not about obtaining `dr`.Is the fact that `dried` and `dry` are reduced to `dr` and we can map documents with `dr` instead of all variations and retrieve them.

Comment: @Cratylus: But you'd also end up matching "draw" and "drew".

Comment: @Cratylus: I think you need to more precisely frame the problem to which you're proposing to apply LCS (what exactly are the inputs, what exactly are the outputs, and what is the purpose of the transformation).

Comment: So every word starting with `pre` will be connected to every other such word? See http://www.morewords.com/starts-with/pre/

Comment: @Olicharlesworth:If "drew" is the past tense of "draw" I don't see why documents containing "drew" should not be considered as close match to a query for "draw" and be retrieved as relative as well

Comment: @Cratylus: No, my point is that they would also stem to "dr" by your algorithm.

Comment: @NPE:This is a valid counter example.Unless we exclude trivial prefixes

Comment: @Olicharlesworth:Yes but stemming is an auxilliary process to document retrieval right?So I would find all documents using `dr` to map them

Comment: @Cratylus: And suffixes. And common letter sequences. In the end you have to build some knowledge about the language into your algorithm.

Comment: @Cratylus: Well, then I suppose it really comes down to what you want your algorithm to do.  If it's sufficient for "dry", "dries", "draw" and "drew" to have a common stem, then prefix trees would work just fine... ;)

Comment: @OliCharlesworth: I agree 100%. I don't think this is an answerable question until we understand the exact problem that's proposed to be solved by this algorithm.

Comment: @NPE:I am not trying to define a new problem here.I ask this under the assumption that stemming is used in search engines to retrieve a set of related (to user's search keyword) documents.If this is a false assumption or this is not the only application of stemming then I would be happy to stand corrected

Answer (score 2):

In many languages, the linguistic stem is often not a common substring. For example the verb "to be" is extremely irregular in many languages.

Even for English nouns, there are exceptional examples such as { index, indexes, indices }. You really want to use "index" as the stem; if you use the much shorter "ind" as the stem, you're going to get collisions, in this case that independent politicians have their abbreviated political party as "ind".